# Choosing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $f(x) = \frac{\sin (x + \alpha) \sin (x + \beta)}{\cos (x + \alpha)\cos (x + \beta)}$ is independent of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, parametric

> Consider the function:
>
> $$f(x) = \frac{\sin (x + \alpha) \sin (x + \beta)}{\cos (x + \alpha)\cos (x + \beta)}$$
>
> Choose the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f(x)$ does not
>   depend on $x$.

Using [Werner's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities), I obtained:

$$f(x) = \frac{\cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)}{\cos(2x + \alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)}$$

If $\alpha = \beta \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$, $f(x) = -1$.

Is this the **only** way to obtain a constant value from $f(x)$? I can't figure out if there are some alternatives, neither I am able to prove that there are not.

Comment: It's also valid for all $\alpha = \beta \pm \frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x + \alpha)\sin(x + \beta)}{\cos(x + \alpha)\cos(x + \beta)} = \frac{\cos(\alpha-\beta) - \cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)}{\cos(\alpha-\beta) + \cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)}$.

We need $f(x; \alpha, \beta) = const$, which is equivalent to $f'(x; \alpha, \beta) = 0, \forall x$.

$f'(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{4\sin(2x+\alpha + \beta)\cos(\alpha - \beta)}{\left(\cos(\alpha-\beta) + \cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)\right)^2} = 0, \forall x \Leftrightarrow \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha-\beta = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

You have that there is a constant $k$ such that
$$
\frac{\cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)}{\cos(2x + \alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)} = k$$
Some algebra turns this into
$$(1 - k)\cos(\alpha - \beta) = (k+1)\cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)$$
This has to hold for every $x$. Since $\cos(2x + \alpha + \beta)$ is a nonconstant function and $(1 - k)\cos(\alpha - \beta)$ is constant, the coefficient $k + 1$ must be zero. So $k = -1$. Plugging this into the above gives
$$2\cos(\alpha - \beta) = 0$$
Hence $\cos(\alpha - \beta) = 0$. The zeroes of $\cos x$ are at ${\pi \over 2} + 2n\pi$ for any integer $n$. Hence in order for $\cos(\alpha - \beta) = 0$ we require
that $\alpha = \beta + {\pi \over 2} + 2n\pi$ for some integer $n$. And going backwards in the above, you can see that any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfying $\alpha = \beta + {\pi \over 2} + 2n\pi$ do in fact satisfy your desired condition.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=-1+\dfrac{\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{\cdots}$$

So,we need $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=0$ to keep  $f(x)$ constant

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. How did you obtain that expression for $f(x)$?

Comment: @BowPark,$$\cos(x+\alpha-(x+\beta))=?$$

Comment: Got it, thank you, this is a clever way to separate the constant part of the function from the $x$-dependent one.